# BrowserSync does not automatically refresh the page with gulp-jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug, browser-sync

I recently created a workspace with gulp. Everything was working normally (auto-reload, sass compilation, minification, and more)
You can see the code on [github](https://github.com/mrdragonxm15/gulp-skeleton)

Today I wanted to add jade to the project. The compilation works well but browserSync does not refresh the page automatically

Here is my code

```js
'use strict'

var gulp = require('gulp')
var jade = require('gulp-jade')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin')
var rename = require('gulp-rename')
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin')
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()

// Compile Jade
gulp.task('jade', function () {
  gulp.src('src/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
})

// Configure CSS tasks.
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

// Configure JS.
gulp.task('js', function () {
  gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

// Configure image stuff.
gulp.task('images', function () {
  gulp.src('src/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

gulp.task('default', ['jade', 'sass', 'js', 'images'], function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './dist'
  })

  gulp.watch('src/*.jade', ['jade'])
  gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
  gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['js'])
  gulp.watch('./dist/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload)
})
```

Comment: You are missing .pipe(browserSync.stream()) in the jade task

Comment: even with this line, the page does not refresh itself.
Here is the output in the command prompt
http://prntscr.com/h346rs

Comment: So if I understand jade correctly, it is outputting html which you hope to reload?  I would try browserSync.reload() instead of stream().  But the question is why doesn't it trigger the gulp.watch of html files?  [You will eventually want return statements on all your tasks but that shouldn't be your issue - but try putting one in 'jade' ala return gulp.src....]

Comment: I updated the code on github but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code and found the error.
Browsersync gets injected into `<head>` element, therefore you need to have that element on your page (still its good to have html/head/body).
Implementing my suggestion from comment (about missing browserSync.stream()) and fixing your jade file to:

```
html
  head
  body
    h1 hello Jade

    ul
      li comment ça va
      li et toi ?

    .box salut comment tu vas ?
```

Solves the problem. BrowserSync now correctly gets inserted into the page :)